# calculate rpm motor to drum roll rpm

Tags: motor, induction-motor, speed

I have a machine used the motor to drive a press roll(a small roller) that sends power to drum roll (big roller).

I need speed 27 rpm for Drum roll and how many RPM for the motor that drives the Press roll. I have a gear ratio, 2 diameter's roller.

I just need to know the calculation

Comment: This is not an electrical engineering question. It is mechanical.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with electrical engineering.

Comment: @jusaca don't electrical engineers have to choose motors to match the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Gearing calculations are based on driven / driver = ratio

So, if you know the rpm of the drum (driven), the ratio (2 diameters - but I don't follow what you mean) then you can calculate the speed of the motor (driver).

However, you should consider most motors have a defined speed so you should work on providing the gears to get the correct output speed from the input.

Comment: we control a motor with VFD